# OpenGL get cursor coordinate on mouse click in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Fairly new to using GLFW, I want to output the cursor coordinate onto the console whenever the left mouse button in clicked. However, I am not getting any output at all.

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    //ESC to quit
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
        return;
    }
    if (key == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS) 
    {
        double xpos, ypos;
        //getting cursor position
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
        cout << "Cursor Position at (" << xpos << " : " << ypos << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do this in the callback of the **key** event? If you want to do something when the mouse button is clicked then you should check that in the mouse button callback.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to get mouse input at keyboard input callback. Notice that `key` corresponds to `GLFW_KEY_*` values. You should set mouse input callback instead:

```
void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    if(button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS) 
    {
       double xpos, ypos;
       //getting cursor position
       glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
       cout << "Cursor Position at (" << xpos << " : " << ypos << endl;
    }
}
```